# Dropdown Date Menus

Tags: ajax, date, drop-down-menu

I am clueless when it comes to JavaScript and Ajax.  Could y'all point me to a simple tutorial site for both?

The algorithm for what I'm trying to accomplish is fairly simple.  I have three drop-down menus to enter a date.  The user selects a year, then a month, then, based on the two previous selections, chooses a date.  So, if a user selects Feb, 2012, the date list will show twenty-nine days.  If he wants to look at Feb. 2013, the date list would show 28 days. Or for another month, show 30 or 31 days.  What sort of function would I need to accomplish this?

Comment: ...and your question is...?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myform">
        <fieldset><legend>Selection Date</legend><label for="year">Year: </label>
            <select name="year" id="year" size="1">
                <option value=" " selected="selected"></option>
                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                <option value="2001">2001</option>
                <option value="2002">2002</option>
            </select>
            <label for="month">Month: </label>
            <select name="month" id="month" size="1">
                <option value=" " selected="selected"></option>
                <option value="1">January</option>
                <option value="2">February</option>
                <option value="3">March</option>
                <option value="4">April</option>
                <option value="5">May</option>
                <option value="6">June</option>
                <option value="7">July</option>
                <option value="8">August</option>
                <option value="9">September</option>
                <option value="10">October</option>
                <option value="11">November</option>
                <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
            <label for="day">Day: </label>
            <select name="day" id="day" size="1">
                <option value=" " selected="selected"></option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="27">27</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="29">29</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="31">31</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function daysInMonth(month, year) {
            var days = new Date(year, month, 0);
            return days.getDate();
        }
        function setDayDrop(dyear, dmonth, dday) {
            var year = dyear.options[dyear.selectedIndex].value;
            var month = dmonth.options[dmonth.selectedIndex].value;
            var day = dday.options[dday.selectedIndex].value;
            if (day == ' ') {
                var days = (year == ' ' || month == ' ') ? 31 : daysInMonth(month, year);
                dday.options.length = 0;
                dday.options[dday.options.length] = new Option(' ', ' ');
                for (var i = 1; i <= days; i++)
                    dday.options[dday.options.length] = new Option(i, i);
            }
        }
        function setDay() {
            var year = document.getElementById('year');
            var month = document.getElementById('month');
            var day = document.getElementById('day');
            setDayDrop(year, month, day);
        }
        document.getElementById('year').onchange = setDay;
        document.getElementById('month').onchange = setDay;
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the speedy response.  I found this on the www that puts a calendar into the form:

[Any Time](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/)